# Pandora-like application with filter

Tags: linux, android, web-apps, music, streaming

I enjoy using Pandora Internet Radio, but I find the station creation tool to be too limiting. I am sensitive to certain sounds (e.g., clapping, snapping, and whistling) and want to tell Pandora to exclude all songs from a station that include such sounds; thumbing down songs does not always give me good results.

What is an application that lets one create music stations that do not include certain sounds?

The application must run on at least one of the following platforms: Android, Web browser, and Linux.

Comment: Could you please give more examples of "certain sounds"? Thanks!